# SIGABRT Error on Button Click xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, click, sigabrt

I am having a strange problem in xcode. i created a button in xib and connected to a function. I am printing the message inside the function. That's all, when i click the button i get the following error. I tried clean and deleted app from my simulator.

`-(IBAction)languageSelection:(id)sender` is my function name

```
-[NSCFString languageSelection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x713cd40
2012-05-03 15:14:35.055 Example[33420:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString languageSelection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x713cd40'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02966919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02ab45de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0296842b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x028d8116 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x028d7cd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x005ece14 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x006766c8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00678b4a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x006776f7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x006102ff -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x005f21ec -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x005f6ac4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7495
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x02dedafa PurpleEventCallback + 1578
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02947dc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x028a8737 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x028a59c3 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x028a5280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x028a51a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x02dec2c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x02dec38d GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x005fab58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  Example                             0x000023c9 main + 121
    22  Example                             0x00002345 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: can you put the code inside that function....?

Comment: Show us some code. Paste the whole -(IBAction)languageSelection:(id)sender function and let us know how the action is triggered. Have you done wiring with Interface builder? Are you declaring the action in code? (If in code, show us the code)

Comment: i found the solution..the problem was that i am initializing my current view controller in app delegate and releasing it after [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; so when i am calling function of the released object, it crashes.

Comment: check ur nib file and see if the button is properly connected to the Action or not.. or else try to use Exception break point. but it would be rather useless coz the error is with the selector but be sure to use the exception break point it is quite handy

Answer (score 2):

this is perhaps you are trying to call a method languageSelection with object that is infact string, but you have passed into another object which has languageSelection method.

this is because you think the object is what you want but the pointer passed the allocated memory to string and hence it will work as string. when you try to call method it crashes because it didn't find the method in string. check your object type just before u use it anywhere

Comment: thanx.. i find the solution..the problem was that i am initializing my current view controller in app delegate and releasing it after [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; so when i am calling function of the released object, it crashes.

Comment: yeah that is the same case. your memory is allocated to some other instance. anyway keep it up. and try your development by enabling zombie objects which will tell you which object released

Comment: in product>edit schems > enable zombie 

but remember disable it when you submit it to appstroe